# MS SQL 2017 Express: Weird error on restoring backup

Tags: database-backups, database-restore, sql-server-2017-express

I'm getting the following error on restoring backup using MS SQL 2017 Express:

```
Msg 3287, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
The file ID 2 on device 'C:\Backups\Test180529.bak' is incorrectly formed and can not be read.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

The test backup was made and was verified on the same MS SQL 2017 Express server instance:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [Test] TO  DISK = N'C:\Backups\Test180529.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, INIT,  NAME = N'Test-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, NO_COMPRESSION,  STATS = 50, CHECKSUM
GO
declare @backupSetId as int
select @backupSetId = position from msdb..backupset where 
database_name=N'Test' and backup_set_id=(select max(backup_set_id) from msdb..backupset where database_name=N'Test' )
if @backupSetId is null begin raiserror(N'Verify failed. Backup information for database ''Test'' not found.', 16, 1) end
RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM  DISK = N'C:\Backups\Test180529.bak' WITH  FILE = @backupSetId,  NOUNLOAD,  NOREWIND
GO
```

Here are the backup process messages:

```
52 percent processed.
Processed 304 pages for database 'Test', file 'Test' on file 1.
100 percent processed.
Processed 2 pages for database 'Test', file 'Test_log' on file 1.
BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed 306 pages in 0.115 seconds (20.788 MB/sec).
The backup set on file 1 is valid.
```

I have used this MS SQL Server 2017 Express instance to successfully restore backups made on other MS SQL Server instances running on other systems.

The problematic MS SQL Server 2017 instance is running on a Windows Server R2 Standard VPS.

**Update**

```
select @@version

Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)   Aug 22 2017 17:04:49   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my MS SQL 2017 Express setup's backup/restore subject issue by using the "SQL Server® 2017 for Microsoft® Windows Latest Cumulative Update"  (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56128).

The version of my MS SQL Server 2017 Express setup now is:

*Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU7) (KB4229789) - 14.0.3026.27 (X64)   May 10 2018 12:38:11   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)*